# MySQL: associating query with table/column

Tags: mysql

I would like to have a column be composed of other columns in a table, e.g. 
column 1 being varchar and column 2 being varchar, then column 3 to be concatenation of column 1 and 2. Column 3 should update when column 1 or 2 are changed.

I currently use a function in my code to concatenate those columns, but I would like to know if it is possible to do it using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns

This documentation talks about generated columns, which are exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not good practice. If you just need to concatenate two columns, you should do it when select:

```
SELECT CONCAT(column_1, ' ', column_2) AS column_3 FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: If I concatenate on select then my select query takes longer. While I don't really care how much space my db uses, I need queries to be as fast as possible.